# Dynamic code generation in Python - Update of Code

Tags: python

I have a python application ready to launch. 
One thing keeps tickling my mind is that the application depends on formal API of several sites to get data.

If one site got their API changed, i have to change the code and ask users to reinstall the new application. It's a lot of work if several things hang on at a time.

I came across exec, which could execute a string like a code snippet.
So, if it works good, I can save the critical code parts sqlite3 table.
In case of any change, I can ask users to do an OTA update from inside the application which will just update the sqlite3 table and code would work as usual.

But just got a hammer, return not working inside exec(), just getting return outside function exception. I don't know what are all others things that will go not working if I use exec.

Working:

```
def func_dyn():
    if 1==1:
        return 1
    else:
        print('test')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    func_dyn();
```

Not Working:

```
global code
code="""if 1==1:
    return 1
else:
    print('test')
"""
def func_dyn():
    global code
    exec(code)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    func_dyn();
```

How to handle the return in exec if exec was inside a function / the way it should be formatted/handled?

Why i need to put the whole code of a function into exec?
since there were many functions like this, I can't store small,small parts which could make code unreadable. So i was thinking to put whole function into string.

Why i need return?
If exceptions arise, the function should return to the caller and execute next.

Comment: Why not put a server of your own inbetween? Then you can update *that* for any changes to external APIs, isolating the client apps. This also has the advantage that you can even out any rough edges on those external APIs and keep the interface with the client simpler and more consistent.

Comment: Sure, But for my case, it would just add one more layer of difficulty. The code required a lot of data processing, which I wish to leave to the local machine of each user.

Comment: That doesn't strike me as more difficult than trying to dynamically execute code on arbitrary clients, and is almost certainly less risky, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Even though exec works in the current context but it doesn't seem to work in the context of the running method, so return was not possible. A workaround is set a flag inside exec and handle return outside. But exec was not a good candidate for my requirement. Instead, I have decided to properly incorporate update functionality in my code via my own standalone updater or via frameworks like pyupdater, esky, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is very difficult to debug. What is the purpose of storing code in SQL anyway? why can't you just prepare an external API file and update that if needed? This can be simply imported by adding a cache folder to your Python path programmatically and will keep your code where it belongs: a `.py` file.